# Find the last $2$ digits of $7^{7^{7^{10217}}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Find the last $2$ digits of $$\large7^{7^{7^{10217}}}$$

So far I have: $17\cdot 601=10217$ and $7=7 \pmod{10}$. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the question again? The title and the body are somewhat related, but ... Also, do you mean the iterated power? Won't the answers to the *Related* questions on the sidebar not settle this as well?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, but to get useful answers you also need do your part and make a clear question as well as search before asking.

Comment: Also, read [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1531660/11619), or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155705/11619) or any of the other scores of questions where the technique is explained.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631143/find-last-two-digits-using-modular-arithmetic

Answer (score 3):

Note that $100=4\cdot 25$. We can find $7^{7^{7^{10217}}}$ mod $4$, $25$, then combine this to get the value mod $100$ using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

$7^4\equiv \left(7^2\right)^2\equiv (-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod{25}$

Therefore $$7^{7^{7^{10217}}}\equiv 7^{7^{7^{10217}}\pmod 4}\equiv 7^{(-1)^{7^{10217}}\pmod 4}\pmod{25}$$

$$\equiv 7^{-1\pmod{4}}\equiv 7^{3}\equiv \left(7^2\right)\cdot 7\equiv (-1)\cdot 7\equiv 18\pmod{25}$$

Also

$$7^{7^{7^{10217}}}\equiv (-1)^{7^{7^{10217}}}\equiv -1\equiv 3\pmod{4}$$

Using the Chinese Remainder theorem, $7^{7^{7^{10217}}}\equiv 43\pmod{100}$.

Comment: You can skip a lot of that work if you realize $7^4\equiv 1\pmod{100}$, but this technique works more generally

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Right, this is what André Nicolas did in the duplicate question I linked in the comments ([this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631143/find-last-two-digits-using-modular-arithmetic)).